# Redirect to specific anchor in Blazor Server Side App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to navigate a user from one page to another page and automatically scroll to a specific anchor on the site.

However, blazor redirects me but the requestes anchor is ignored. Does anybody know how I can achive this?

In my app, the user becomes redirected within the code behind file of my razor component.

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/Lagerregal/Auftrag/{Belegnummer}#{Position.BPOS_N_POSID + Position.UrlParameter}");
```

Thanks in advance!
Marvin

Comment: There is a [Blog for that](https://chrissainty.com/fragment-routing-with-blazor/).

Answer (score 2):

Henk Holterman commented blog is really nice. If you want to navigate without using JavaScript you can try this -

```
@inject NavigationManager Nav;
<a @onclick="OnChanged"> Section 1 </a>
<a href="@Nav.BaseUri/Descriptions#section2"> Section 2 </a>

 void OnChanged(MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          Nav.NavigateTo($"{Nav.BaseUri}/Descriptions#section1");

       }

@page "/Descriptions" 
 <h3 id="section1">Section 1</h3>
 <p>This is first Section</p>

 <h3 id="section2">Section 2</h3>
 <p>This is second Section</p>
```